# Find radius of convergence using Cauchy's Hadamard or from a series of simpler terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

So let's try to find the radius of convergence for 2 questions. I think I solved it using Cauchy's Hadamard but I don't know what it means to do it from a series of simpler terms.

From a series of simpler series Theorems:

> The derived series of a power series has the same radius of convergence as the original series.

or

> A power series obtained by integrating a series term by term has the same radius of convergence as the original series.

First equation in question:

1. $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n(n-1)}{2^n} (z - 2i)^{n}$$

Cauchy Hadamard says:

$$Radius = lim_{n \to \infty} \left | \frac{a_n}{a{n+1}}\right |$$

So in this case $a_n = \frac{n(n-1)}{2^n}$ and $a_{n+1} = \frac{n+1(n)}{2^{n+1}}$. This limit approaches 2 as $n \to \infty$

But how can we verify this by comparison to another series?

What about this next question:

2. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{3^n} (z + 2i)^{2n}$$

My book says the radius = $\sqrt{3}$ but I keep getting 3.

$a = \frac{n}{3^n}$ and $a_{n+1} \frac{n+1}{3^{n+1}}$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{3^n} \cdot \frac{3^{n+1}}{n+1} = 3$$

But it's supposed to be $\sqrt{3}$/

Is there another way to solve this radius without using Cauchy's Hadamard and comparing it to another series that we know like the geometric series?

Comment: For the first one, let $f(z)=\sum2^{-n}(z-2i)^n$, and consider $(z-2i)^2f''(z)$. For the second, you're overlooking the $2$ in the exponent of $z+2i$.

Comment: Making any progress?

Comment: I think I know what went wrong in the second one. that makes sense. Still stuck on the first

Comment: OK. So, what do you get when you let $f(x)=\sum2^{-n}(z-2i)^n$ and then calculate $(z-2i)^2f''(z)$?

Comment: Aren't I supposed to compare this to another series? Why am I taking the double deriavtive of this? The double derivative of this seems quite complicated... am I doing this to just find the Taylor series by hand?

Comment: Get back to me after you have calculated $(z-2i)^2f''(z)$. [oops, where I had $f(x)$ in a previous comment, I meant $f(z)$]

Comment: I guess you have lost interest in the question. Too bad.

Comment: I dont know how to do it

Comment: What is f(z) here and how do I differentiate it twice? Can I do it term by term?

Comment: In my very first comment, I wrote "let $f(z)=\sum2^{-n}(z-2i)^n$" so that tells you what $f(z)$ is. And, yes, you can differentiate a power series term-by-term. Also, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry in it.

Comment: So: what do you get as the second derivative of $f(z)$?

Comment: OK, maybe that's too hard. What's the derivative with respect to $z$ of $(z-2i)^n$?

Comment: With respect to z, the derivative is $n(z-2i)^{n-1} \cdot 1$ via chain rule right? @GerryMyerson

Comment: Good. So, what's the derivative of $2^{-n}(z-2i)^n$?

Comment: $2^{-n} \cdot n(z-2i)^{n-1} + (z-2i)^{n} \cdot -n2^{-n-1}$ @GerryMyerson via multiplication rule of derivatives

Comment: We're still talking about derivative with respect to $z$. $n$ is a constant, not a variable. The derivative of $2^{-n}$ with respect to $z$ is zero. So, try again.

Comment: $2^{-n} \cdot n(z-2i)^{n-1}$

Comment: Good. Now, the second derivative of $2^{-n}(z-2i)^n$?

Comment: $2^{-n} \cdot (n^2 - n)(z-2i)^{n-2}$

Comment: Fine. So, what's the second derivative of $\sum_n(2^{-n}(z-2i)^n)$?

Comment: same thing but with a $\sum$ in frront of it?

Comment: Good. Now: $(z-2i)^2f''(z)$, where $f(z)=\sum_n2^{-n}(z-2i)^n$?

Comment: Come on, we're almost there!